# Is possible to pass route parameter to name method laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

Is this possible?

```
Route::get('/items/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'getItem'])->name('items' . 
$id);
```

is this possible or is there any way to do this?

Comment: no you can't, but you don't need to. If your route has required parameters and you call that route with `route('name', ['id' => $id])`

Comment: @BenGooding He's right. you should pass dynamic data like that.

Comment: @moTmh
can we know reasone why you are doing like that?